# Could not enter folder /usr/share/icons/XX Error after folder copy

Tags: icons, directory

I'm on Ubuntu 15.10, downloaded icons from https://github.com/0rAX0/uniform-icon-theme.

I got error:

> Could not enter folder /usr/share/icons/uniform-icon-theme-master.

...after copying the files from downloads.

The icon folder appears in unity-tweak-tool yet after applying the icons it loads some basic ones, not the ones downloaded.

Could you please help?

Please take a look in the snapshot below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDDot.jpg

Regards,

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forget which user nautilus (the file browser) runs as, but it is not root, and since (most) everything under `/usr` is owned by root (use `ls -l` on files/directories in question), the file browser won't be able to display the contents.

Answer (score 0):

trying to load the icons that I downloaded in a folder from Github.

...anyway now I got what I wanted via another method, terminal, somehow (only one) icon theme wokred (numix circle) this way:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:numix/ppa 

sudo apt-get update 

sudo apt-get install numix-icon-theme numix-icon-theme-circle
```

thank you for your answers,

Regards,